# Trying to display eloquent data base from ID's

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to create a record base from ID of an order transaction.

I have here the ORDERS, CAMPANIES and CURRENCIES models.

Now I want the ORDER to get the ID from a URL Parameter, and then the companies should grab the `company_id` from Orders same with currency, I want to grab the `currency_id` from orders.

Here's what I came up so far:

```
public function create($order_id)
{
    $order = Orders::find($order_id)->where('id', '=', $order_id)->get();
    $company = Companies::where('id', '=', $order['company_id'])->get();
    $currency = Currencies::where('id', '=', $order['company_id'])->get();
    $banks = Banks::all('name','acronym','id')->get();
    return view('orderPayments.create', compact('order'))
        ->with('company', $company)
        ->with('currency', $currency)
        ->with('banks', $banks);
}
```

**currencies model**

```
public function orderPayments()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Orderpayments', 'id','currency_id');
}
```

**Companies Model**

```
public function orderPayments()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Orderpayments', 'id','company_id');
}
```

**Order Payments Model**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Companies', 'id','company_id');
}

public function currency()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Currencies', 'id', 'currency_id');
}    

public function bank()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Bank', 'id', 'currency_id');
}
```

How can I achieve it? thank you so much in advance!

## UPDATE

I just applied @sandy's answer. I checked if the $order has a content so I echod the $order by doing this, {{ $order }} The return value is ok.

[image]

but when I calling the other attributes like $order->grandtotal, or $order->companies->comp_name the error is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship between your models is a [One To Many](http://One%20To%20Many) relationship you should use `belongsTo` in your relations like this:

**OrderPayment Model**

```
 public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Companies','company_id');
}

public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Currencies','currency_id');
}    

public function bank()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bank', 'currency_id');
}
```

Also, the second parameter on the function should be your foreign key.

**Answering your question:**

If you want to access the relations of a given Order you could do this:

```
$order = Order::find($order_id);
$order->company; // this will return the company
$order->currency; // this will return the currency
```

If you want to display in your view:

```
{{$order->company->anyCompanyAttribute}}
```

**Note:** 
You should name your models in **SINGULAR** like Currency, Company. Not in plural.

Comment: This works! probably in my next project I'll make all my models in singular. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad i could help, friend :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$order = Orders::with(['company','currency'])->where('id', '=', $order_id)->get();
```

Comment: Hi @sandy I think it works! how can I display it in my blade? let say I will display the value from companies or currency?

Comment: $order->company like this

Comment: Ex. you want to display name of company then use $order->company->name

Comment: its weird because I am doing it that way but doesn't work. like for example, in Orders (model) it has a grand total value, so I am trying to display it this way, {{ $order->grandtotal }} but the error said, Property [grandtotal] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\wamp64\www\brandExpertPOS\resources\views\orderPayments\create.blade.php)

Comment: send your table structure of order table

Comment: or may be its just because you have no order of the given id

Comment: Hi @sandy I just update my question. I added the screenshots

Comment: ok in your query use ->first() instead of ->get() this will resolve your issue. @LitoLozada

Comment: Thanks @sandy I will take note of this!

Comment: @LitoLozada if my answer is working then please again mark it as answer